# Instantiation of class

Tags: c#

I am newbie in C#.I have one confusion.

There are two classes A and B.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A objA = new A();

            A objB = new B();
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public void MethodA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method of A class");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public void MethodB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method of B class");
        }
    }
}
```

Now the confusion which I have is that what is the meaning of:

```
A objB = new B();
```

I have seen and instantiated class like thi:

```
A objB = new A();
```

Can anyone tell me why we used:

```
A objB = new B();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Since class `B` inherits from `A`, instances of `B` are also instances of `A`, and [polymorphism](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/polymorphism/intro/) guarantees than any instance of `B` can be assigned to an `A`.

Your code's only purpose seems to be demonstrating this concept.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing here is creating a new `B`, but you're treating it as an `A`. After this, you can do e.g. this:

```
A objB = new B();
B realObjB = (B)objB;
```

You don't use this in code directly, but you can use this for methods that only accept an `A`, but where you really want it to be a `B`.

A concrete example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Truck truck = new Truck();

        TellMeHowManyWheelsThisHas(truck);
    }

    private static void TellMeHowManyWheelsThisHas(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This vehicle has {0} wheels", vehicle.HowManyWheelsDoIHave());
    }
}

abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract int HowManyWheelsDoIHave();
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override int HowManyWheelsDoIHave()
    {
        return 4;
    }
}

class Truck : Vehicle
{
    public override int HowManyWheelsDoIHave()
    {
        return 8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A derived class object can be represented a its base class object.

i.e in your case class B is derived from class A. hense `A objB` (which is of Base class type) can represent an object of type `B`. 
But in this case objB can only see base class A's Member functions and properties.

google for Upcasting/DownCasting for more information

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would be used in the case where you only care that objB is an `A` and the fact that it is really a `B` doesn't matter.

An example is better served by a more descriptive example of polymorphism.

something akin to this: (method bodies missing for brevity)

```
class Vehicle { public void Drive(); }
class Boat : Vehicle { public void LowerAnchor(); }
class Car : Vehicle { public void SoundHorn(); }

Vehicle boat = new Boat();
boat.Drive();
Vehicle car = new Car();
car.Drive();
```

The fact that `boat` and `car` are actually `Boat` and `Car` is irrelevant, all you want to do is drive. The implementation of `Drive()` may also differ, but again you're only interested in being able to drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A objA = new A();
            A objB = new B();
            Console.ReadLine(); // only used to keep the output on-screen
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method of A class");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method of B class");
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this code example does a better job of providing an output that reflects what is happening.  I moved the methods within each class to the constructor to illustrate what really happens when you inherit from an object.  This is the output:

```
method of A class
method of A class
method of B class
```

The original code example was probably designed to show a simple example of inheritance but was poorly written.